# Build on VSTS fail to get source randomly

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfvc

We use TFVC to version control. After migrate from TFS 2017 to VSTS on cloud, our build will fail randomly. Everytime when it fail, it complaint:

```
2017-08-15T03:58:35.9681298Z ##[command]tf vc workspace /new /location:local /permission:Public ws_6_14 /collection:https://slb1-swt-xxx.visualstudio.com/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
2017-08-15T03:58:38.8432402Z TF14044: Access Denied: User Drilling Shared Components Build Service (slb1-swt) needs the AdminWorkspaces global permission(s).
2017-08-15T03:58:38.8578892Z ##[error]Exit code 100 returned from process: file name 'tf', arguments 'vc workspace /new /location:local /permission:Public ws_6_14 /collection:https://slb1-swt-xxx.visualstudio.com/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt'.
```

Anyone has some idea about this error and how to deal with the "AdminWorkspaces global permission"?

Update:

1. And in slb1-swt-xxx > Project Collection Build Service Accounts, the "Create a workspace" is already set to "Allow".
2. The agent (agent.version is 2.120.1) is created from scratch in local machine. Which means even the _work folder is empty, still meet this issue.

Comment: Can you please confirm that, within your project collection -> security -> Project Collection Build Service Accounts -> Drilling Shared Components Build Service, that Create a workspace attribute is set

Comment: What's the result if you set Administer workspaces to Allow too? Do you use private build agent? Try to delete all folders and files in agent working folder (e.g. [agent folder]\_work\XXX) and try again.

Comment: You are using private build agent, try to setup a new agent and queue build with this agent and check the result.